# ShareActionProvider Drop down menu color from AppCompat v7

Tags: android, android-theme, shareactionprovider

Just tried ShareActinProvider from AppCompat v7 and while the drop down from the action bar menu is light and good, the drop down from the ShareActionProvider share button is dark. 
This is the style applied.

```
<style name="Theme.Pinnr" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#C62828</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#B71C1C</item>
 </style>
```

I want both menus to have the same color.

Here is the bad menu image:

[image]

Here is the good menu image:

[image]

**Update**
I am in fact aware that I can change the color of that popup background with this code

```
<style name="Theme.Pinnr.listPopupWindowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#eeeeee</item>
</style>
```

My question is why its happening and shouldn't just behave like the other menu. And hopefully how do I set it to match the other menu without hardcoding the color for the popup

Comment: Post your images on a public sharing website, and one of us will embed the images into your post.

Comment: The bad menu image https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-vql2NwFzwRWGk4Y3hJWDk1YUk&authuser=0

The good menu image
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-vql2NwFzwRTHlnZnVrVnprblE&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it was because I was based on Ligh.DarkActionBar theme. Changed to just the Light theme and it worked fine.